# How to find extreme hills biomes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any effective way to find extreme hills or extreme hills edge biomes for emerald farming since they are so rare?

Comment: As a side note, as they are so rare (even in extreme hills) it is really inefficient trying to earn emeralds just by mining. The hours spent mining for emeralds can be more efficiently used farming and selling things such as sugar cane, wheat, and wool to villagers; see [Villager Trading](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Trading).

Comment: @IQAndreas If you do it manually, yes. But with a mining turtle or quarry I'm not sure.

Comment: if you have mystcraft then just create a extreme hills age and stripmine that

Comment: @IQAndreas they are not as rare as you would think. I have been playing on a new world for about a week and have found over 40 diamonds and 30 emeralds. The best place to find them in my opinion is an abandoned mineshaft in the extreme hills biome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The vanilla/survival mode way?** Grab a bed, a pick, a weapon, and some torches and just start heading out in one direction until you find extreme hills. I would also recommend bringing materials with to create a nether portal, making the return trip 8x faster.

**If you are not opposed to using external tools or mods,** there are several tools which let you find biomes. The only one I know of off the top of my head (although there are several out there) is [Amidst](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v35-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder-172/) which creates a map of the biome layout in your specific seed. This will help you find that specific biome without having to create those chunks by exploring the area first.